# creating common header and sidebar across all the page using react router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

> App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
          <div>
            <Header />
            <div className="main">
              <SideBar />
              <Route
                path="/dashboard"
                exact
                component={RequireAuth(Dashboard)}
              />
              <Route path="/profile" exact component={RequireAuth(Profile)} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
   );
 }
}
```

Here i want Header and Sidebar to be common across all the pages while i change the route and i am getting the result but i think it is not a standard way to do so,**please suggest and help me,that how should i create the common layout for 
 some set of pages and another layout for other pages**,like

```
 <Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
   <layout1>
    <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={RequireAuth(Dashboard)}/>
    <Route path="/profile" exact component={RequireAuth(Profile)} />
   </layout1>

   <layout2>
    <Route path="/otherinfo1" exact component={RequireAuth(OtherInfo1)}/>
    <Route path="/otherinfo2" exact component={RequireAuth(OtherInfo2)} />
   </layout2>
  </Switch>
 </Router>
```

> i am using react router 4.2.2

and every time i login and redirect to dashboard, jquery functionality doesn't work, always i need to refresh the page to run jquery related stuffs(if could help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prefix, you two sets of routes with an identifier and set that as a Route path, All other routes can go inside the respective container Layout

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
   <Route path="/layout1" component={FirstContainer}/>
   <Route path="/layout2" component={SecondContainer}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Then you `FirstContainer` would be like

```
const FirstContainer = ({match}) => (
    <div>
         {/* other stuff */}
         <Route path={`${match.path}/dashboard`} exact component={RequireAuth(Dashboard)}/>
         <Route path={`${match.path}/profile`} exact component={RequireAuth(Profile)} />
         {/* other stuff */}
    </div>

)
```

and `SecondContainer`

```
const SecondContainer = ({match}) => (
    <div>
         {/* other stuff */}
         <Route path={`${match.path}/otherinfo1`} exact component={component={RequireAuth(OtherInfo1)}}/>
         <Route path={`${match.path}/otherinfo2`} exact component={RequireAuth(OtherInfo2)} />
         {/* other stuff */}
    </div>

)
```

Comment: i tried but template literals doesn't work there "<Route path=`${match.path}/dashboard` exact component={RequireAuth(Dashboard)}/>"

Comment: i did that but after login i am unable to view dashboard page check this code  [link](https://gist.github.com/tapandave08/112c1dc71171ba0167733180eaff7c99)

Comment: where are you redirecting to after login, I mean what is the path that you redirect to

Comment: here is my [link](https://gist.github.com/tapandave08/f0699d00f79ce6f9eefa339a00979930) i am redirecting to dashboard

Comment: In fact the link should not be `history.push('/dashboard');` but `history.push('/layout/dashboard');` since we have prefixed our Routes with `layout` in the parent

Comment: yes i tried that also, but was not working just showing me blank page

Comment: One more thing, you parent route `<Route path="/layout" exact component={Container} />` has an exact in it which you should remove, otherwise the child routes like `/layout/dashboard` wont ever match

Comment: yes thanks it worked well but what happen is after login when i do history.push('/layout/dashboard'),layout appears fine but whatever stuff done by [materialize](https://react-materialize.github.io/#/) framework like dropdown toggle,sidenav toggle etc. are not working,always i need to refresh the page,and then it works well,please if you could help

Comment: @tapandave, I am not really sure about that, maybe you can try somethings and if you dont find a solution ask another question and someone may be able to help

Comment: but one question again as some user type in url only /layout then he could see the common design,but i want them only to access the url like layout/dashboard,layout/profile,etc. not directly /layout, and if they access /layout then they should redirect back to layout/dashboard

Comment: in the Container component, add `Redirect from='/layout' to='/layout/dashboard'/>`

Comment: okay i did that,but in console warning appears "You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/layout/dashboard"",whenever i navigate from one route to other

Comment: Can you add the part in which you have added the Redirect and ask another question, If will have a look at that