# Setup path of Route to exclude a couple of paths

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm using React router v4. I have a component, for example, Header which is required for all pages excluding a couple special pages. 
Can I defined 'path' for Route to implement it?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327423/creating-common-header-and-sidebar-across-all-the-page-using-react-router/47328327#47328327

Comment: Is there any decision where the path doesn't content a name of chosen template? Be more precise I have SiginPage with route '/signin' where there's not Header and the rest of pages must content it. According to the link it makes me create route for SiginPage smth like that '/withoutHeader/signin' and the rest pages must have prefix smth like '/withHeader'. I would like to avoid a usage of these prefixes.

Comment: If its just signIn, you could just, use '/' and '/signIn' avoiding any prefixes